# TypeError: videoResponsive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'

Tags: python, iframe

I am trying out yt-iframe python library.
Following code :

```
channel = yt.channel('https://www.youtube.com/user/ouramazingspace') # (Required)
width = '560' # (Optional)
height = '315' # (Optional)
responsive = True # (Optional)

# Fixed size iframes
iframes = yt.getFrames(channel, width=width, height=height)

# Responsive iframes
iframes = yt.getFrames(channel, responsive=responsive)
```

Gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 18, in <module>
    iframes = yt.getFrames(channel, responsive=responsive)
  File "D:\Level 4\PROJECT\PetProjects\SplitFrames\venv\lib\site-packages\yt_iframe\yt.py", line 134, in getFrames
    frame = videoResponsive(vid, width=width, height=height)
TypeError: videoResponsive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the library is passing invalid arguments on line 134 of the library, so this isn't easily solvable because it's a bug you didn't create.

```
  File "D:\Level 4\PROJECT\PetProjects\SplitFrames\venv\lib\site-packages\yt_iframe\yt.py", line 134, in getFrames
    frame = videoResponsive(vid, width=width, height=height)
TypeError: videoResponsive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'
```

I just looked up the API documents, and videoResponsive() does not seem to take in a `width` keyword argument. This isn't an issue with your code, but rather, it seems like an issue with the library/ package you are using, as that's where the bug is coming from. I'd suggest trying out a different library, or making a pull request or make an issue on the library's github page for the maintainer to fix the bug.

```
# code example from https://pypi.org/project/yt-iframe/
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzIQOQGKeyI' # (Required)
layout = 'singlecolumn' # (Optional)

video = yt.videoResponsive(url, layout=layout) # Get HTML
```

I opened a ticket on github to fix the bug [here](https://github.com/RobbyB97/yt-iframe-python/issues/6).